# Каким способом лучше заполнять datalist?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

На сайте есть элемент datalist который должен выводить города в зависимости от того что вводит пользователь. То есть например пользователь начинает вводить **казан** и в datalist показываются возможные варианты **Казанская Казань Казановская Казанское** и он должен выбрать ему нужный один город из списка. Вопрос заключается в том, как лучше реализовать такой функционал: Достать все 3000 записей из базы данных и с этих данных искать или после ввода каждой буквы обращаться в базу получая каждый раз возможные варианты(используя ajax)? Заранее спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: Ответы на подобные вопросы сильно зависят от мнения. И так хорошо, и этак хорошо, минусы и там и там есть, как разрулить подобный трейдофф -- вопрос вкусовщины. Сделайте любым способом. Потом, если время останется - сделайте другим. Выберите любой.

Comment: @A K Сейчас у меня сделан 2 вариант

Comment: В принципе ответ действительно будет субъективным и зависит от бизнес требований, кого то не испугает такая нагрузка на бэк, кому то проще вытянуть все варианты и фильтровать на стороне клиента.